# What is the correct way to update the sortorder of a list in mongodb without refreshing the page using react-drag-reorder?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

The extention used for reorder in my react website is [react-drag-reorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drag-reorder), My website is running on reactjs for the frontend and bacend is handled by nodejs and mongodb (Mongoose as database module)

My List Schema is defined as follows

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    name        : {type: String , default : ""},
    sort        : {type: Number , default : 0},
    sortChanged : {type: Date , default : new Date()}
})
```

My sort page is queried using the following

```
exports.getAll  = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {  
    let lists = await List.find({})
                    .select("name _id sortChanged sort") 
                    .sort({sort:-1,sortChanged:-1})
    res.status(200).json({lists : lists}); 
});
```

In my reactjs code , I have used the following for listing and sorting using react-drag-reorder

```
const changePosition = async (currentPos, newPos) => {
        let currentData  = fmodels[currentPos];
        let movedData    = fmodels[newPos];
        let config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
         try{
            const res = await axios.post(api+"/lists/changeSort",{ 
                newPos : lists.length-newPos,
                _id    : currentData._id

        }catch(error){

        }
}


{ (lists.length > 0 ) && <Draggable onPosChange={(currentPos , newPos)=>{
    changePosition(currentPos,newPos);
}}>
    {lists.map((data, idx) => {
    return (
        <div key={idx} className="flex-item dragdrop">
        {model.data}
        </div>
    );
    })}
</Draggable>
}
```

changeSort code on my server side is as follows

```
exports.changeSort  = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {  
    List.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id }, {sort:req.body.newPos, sortChanged : new Date()}, { new: true })
    .exec((error, dat) => {
        if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
        if(dat){
            return res.status(200).json({ dat : dat});
        }
    })
});
```

The issue is that the sort will work correctly for the first movement only,
ie if I moved 7th (sort order is 1 for that) and it will change to 7

I understood the issue that the moving first item will only changes its sortorder value no other items will not change on first movement [image: Screenshot is added]

Can someone help to give me a best way to handle this sort case?